# irkernel extremely slow on easy command with large dataframe

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have installed irkernel following standard instruction. When trying to work on a large dataset (9M rows * 70 cols), it takes forever to run an easy command such as print(db[1,1]) or head(db) in jupyter-notebook irkernel.

I could run these commands in seconds on rstudio.

Is there anything I could improve in order to work on this dataset efficiently through jupyter-notebook? What could be the potential problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i've got the same problem in the past couple of months. any solutions yet?

Comment: @Zhiya I tried another version of anaconda and it worked. http://repo.continuum.io/archive/ Try check a version of python 3.5 (anaconda 4.2)